# Using connect-busboy and node.js and upload to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, busboy

Im really struggling with uploading to S3.
I want to upload a video file to S3 using STREAMING (ie not saving temp file on the server and then uploading to s3)

I dont know how to set the s3 upload function in order for it to read from stream.
It seems like connect-busboy creats a stream that no one reads for it.

This is my code:

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.body.FileBox);
req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {

     //videoUpload.upload(req.body.FileBox);
     var params = {
         Bucket: 'videogamblerside',
         Key: "chek",
         Body: file,
         ContentType: "video/mp4"
     };
    console.log(file);
    //file.resume();
    //  file.resume();
    s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Probably you want to add `ContentLength`

This code sample works for me:

```
busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {



        s3Client.putObject({
          Bucket: bucket,
          Key: filename,
          ACL: 'public-read',
          Body: file,
          ContentLength: 3000,
        }, function(err, data) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("done", data);
          console.log("https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/" + bucket + '/' + random_name);
        })

    });



    busboy.on('finish', function() {
      res.send("That's all folks!");
    });
```